# Removing Flash meta-policy communication warning

Tags: apache-flex, flash, cross-domain

I am communicating to an external server via a `URLLoader` and receiving the following warning:

> Warning: Domain *domain name* does not
>   specify a meta-policy.  Applying
>   default meta-policy 'master-only'. 
>   This configuration is deprecated.  See
>   http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files
>   to fix this problem.

The provided link redirected me to another page, which didn't really explain how to remove this warning. It looks like it might involve modifying the crossdomain.xml file on the server, but I'm not sure exactly how. Any thoughts on how to remove this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to update the crossdomain file on the server depending on your needs.

For instance:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

... specifies that only the crossdomain file at the server root is used.

There's a good article on DevNet that explains the various settings: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security_03.html